# How does this work? type = type || 'any';

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain me how this expression works?

```
type = type || 'any';
```

Does it mean that if type is undefined use 'any'?

Comment: MDN Docs to the rescue: [Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Comment: Jaidev why did you feel the need to edit out his 'Thanks in advance' from the question? Was that really necessary?

Comment: A short but interesting paper could be written on the subject using the short-circuiting of `&&` and `||` in JavaScript expressions, especially as a replacement for the ternary operator.  The simplest case is the one the OP gives -- using the first value, if set to something "interesting", otherwise the constant given as the value -- but there are more complicated use-cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `type` is "falsy" (i.e. `false`, or `undefined` or an empty string or null or undefined), then use "any"

Comment: or NaN  (@nnnnnn -- did I miss any others?)

Answer (score 3):

If the variable `type` is a “falsey” value, it is set to the string `'any'`, otherwise it is set to its own value.

Answer (score 2):

That's a `true OR alternative` condition. Less verbose, basically.

Test it out: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/ussBZ/3/

```
var type = 0;

type = type || 'any';
alert('0 = ' + type); // alerts 0 = any

type = 1;

type = type || 'any';
alert('1 = ' + type); // alerts 1 = 1

type = true;

type = type || 'any';
alert('true = ' + type); // alerts true = true

type = false;

type = type || 'any';
alert('false = ' + type); // alerts false = any

type = 'foobar';

type = type || 'any';
alert('foobar = ' + type); // alerts foobar = foobar

type = '';

type = type || 'any';
alert('\'\' = ' + type); // alerts '' = any

type = null;

type = type || 'any';
alert('null = ' + type); // alerts null = any

type = new Array();

type = type || 'any';
alert('new Array() = ' + type); // alerts new Array() = 

type = [];

type = type || 'any';
alert('[] ' + type); // alerts [] = 

type = {};

type = type || 'any';
alert('{} = ' + type); // alerts {} = [object Object]

type = new Object;

type = type || 'any';
alert('new Object = ' + type); // alerts new Object = [object Object]
```

Answer (score 1):

That means, if type evaluates to false, use 'any'. That is if type is undefined, false, 0, ...